# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_add_privacy_policy_content() in /wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1822

Tags: errors, privacy

```
/**
     * Add the suggested privacy policy text to the policy postbox.
     *
     * @since 4.9.6
     */
    public static function add_suggested_content() {
        $content = self::get_default_content( true );
        wp_add_privacy_policy_content( __( 'WordPress' ), $content );
    }
```

I see the function is added since wordpress version 4.9.6 and my wordpress version is 4.9.8
What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is 
the function was defined in `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` as mentioned here [https://wpseek.com/function/wp_add_privacy_policy_content/](http://wp_add_privacy_policy_content)
When I opened the `plugin.php` file of a clean wordpress 4.9.8 version I found the function wp_add_privacy_policy_content() already defined, whereas in my wordpress 4.9.8 version It was missing so I added it back

***Kindly make sure the function is defined in plugin.php***

```
/**
 * Helper function for adding content to the Privacy Policy Guide.
 *
 * Plugins and themes should suggest text for inclusion in the site's privacy policy.
 * The suggested text should contain information about any functionality that affects user privacy,
 * and will be shown on the Privacy Policy Guide screen.
 *
 * A plugin or theme can use this function multiple times as long as it will help to better present
 * the suggested policy content. For example modular plugins such as WooCommerse or Jetpack
 * can add or remove suggested content depending on the modules/extensions that are enabled.
 * For more information see the Plugin Handbook:
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/privacy/suggesting-text-for-the-site-privacy-policy/.
 *
 * Intended for use with the `'admin_init'` action.
 *
 * @since 4.9.6
 *
 * @param string $plugin_name The name of the plugin or theme that is suggesting content for the site's privacy policy.
 * @param string $policy_text The suggested content for inclusion in the policy.
 */
function wp_add_privacy_policy_content( $plugin_name, $policy_text ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        _doing_it_wrong(
            __FUNCTION__,
            sprintf(
                /* translators: %s: admin_init */
                __( 'The suggested privacy policy content should be added only in wp-admin by using the %s (or later) action.' ),
                '<code>admin_init</code>'
            ),
            '4.9.7'
        );
        return;
    } elseif ( ! doing_action( 'admin_init' ) && ! did_action( 'admin_init' ) ) {
        _doing_it_wrong(
            __FUNCTION__,
            sprintf(
                /* translators: %s: admin_init */
                __( 'The suggested privacy policy content should be added by using the %s (or later) action. Please see the inline documentation.' ),
                '<code>admin_init</code>'
            ),
            '4.9.7'
        );
        return;
    }

    if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Privacy_Policy_Content' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/misc.php' );
    }

    WP_Privacy_Policy_Content::add( $plugin_name, $policy_text );
}
```